# Would increasing system memory speed reduce a Von Neumann Architecture bottleneck?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache, cpu, memory-access, cache

A Von Neumann Architecture bottleneck is a limit on the amount of data a computer can process due to limited bandwidth between the CPU and RAM. Possible mitigations to the problem according to Wikipedia are...

> - Providing a cache between the CPU and the main memory
> - Providing separate caches or separate access paths for data and instructions
> - Using branch predictor algorithms and logic
> - Providing a limited CPU stack or other on-chip scratchpad memory to reduce memory access
> - Implementing the CPU and the memory hierarchy as a system on chip, providing greater locality of reference and thus reducing latency and increasing throughput between processor registers and main memory.

I know that increasing the number of data lanes between the CPU and RAM would help, but would increasing the system memory speed also help?

Comment: `limited bandwidth` do you know further processing speed related properties of memory?

Comment: In addition to "the other obvious measure" [Shashank V M's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/136611/19966) equates with memory speed, it mentions memory size, which has an influence on applicable data structures&algorithms.

Comment: Obviously increasing the speed would reduce the bottleneck. But it's already as fast as we can make it. Why would we make one slower than that???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, increasing the memory speed won't help solve the Von Neumann architecture bottleneck. The reason is **as memory size is increased the time required to access the memory contents increases**. So no matter how fast the memory is, if it is large it will be slower. So faster, smaller memories called caches are used to provide the illusion of a large, fast memory to the user.